# Add class to specific url anchor with JQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor

I need to change the color of a menu scrolling from a section to another.
When the url contains a specific anchor, the menu should change color. 
I tried the following  but in this case the menu changes ONLY if I'm on the specific anchor and it doesn't change anymore when I scroll to another anchor again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("#7") > -1) {
    $('.menu_item a').css('color', '#000');
  } else {
    $('.menu_item a').css('color', '#fff');
  }
});
```

Comment: Well yeah - you have to call the code *on scroll* - the above code doesn't constantly re-execute when it feels like it, it does it once, when the document is ready.

Comment: Great, simple and correct !

Comment: Actually - @adeneo has a better idea, fire the event on hashchange. See the answer he provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an event handler that fires when the hash changes as well, not just on pageload, as the hashchange doesn't reload the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("#7") > -1) {
            $('.menu_item a').css('color','#000');
        } else {
            $('.menu_item a').css('color','#fff');
        }
    });    
});
```

You could also use the scroll event, but as there is a specific event for hashchanges, and the hash has to change to get a different result, you'd probably be better of with the `hashchange` event.